# Find the mode value and frequency in R

Tags: r, statistics, data, data-cleaning, dplyr

I'm trying to come up with a function in R that gives the mode value of a column along with the number of times (or frequency) that the value occurs. I want it to exclude missing (or blank) values, and treat ties by showing both values. When there are no repeating values I want it to return the first-appearing value that is found along with its frequency 1.

```
"Name         Color
 Drew         Blue
 Drew         Green
 Drew         Red
 Bob          Green
 Bob          Green
 Bob          Green
 Bob          Blue
 Jim          Red 
 Jim          Red
 Jim          blue
 Jim          blue

mode of Drew = Blue, 1
mode of Bob = Green, 3
mode of jim = Red, Blue, 2
```

Here's the function code i have so far, it excludes NAs but does not show both values when there is a tie and does not show frequency. Any help appreciated!

`mode <- function(x) {
  if ( anyNA(x) ) x = x[!is.na(x)]
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a custom function to do this. Let `dplyr` handle it. Assuming your data is in a dataframe named `df`, here is what it might look like:

```
df %>%                                       # Set up the pipe
subset(complete.cases(df)) %>%               # Removes rows with NA values
group_by(Name) %>%                           # Groups by the Name column
count(Color) %>%                             # Counts each Color by Name, creates a new column n
mutate(max = max(n)) %>%                     # Creates a new column for the max(n) by Name
subset(n == max(n)) %>%                      # Keeps only those rows where n equals max(n)
mutate(Keep == case_when(                    # Creates a dummy logical column named 'Keep'
   n > 1 ~ TRUE,                             # That is TRUEfor n > 1 to keep ties
   n == 1 & Color == head(Color, 1) ~ TRUE,  # That is TRUE for the first row of n = 1
   TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>%                        # That is FALSE for all other cases
subset(Keep) %>%                             # Keeps only those rows where Keep is TRUE
select(Name, Mode = Color, n)                # Keeps only the Name, Color, and n columns and
                                             # renames Color as Mode
```

Here is the output

```
 # A tibble: 3 x 3
 # Groups:   Name [3]
   Name  Mode   Count
   <fct> <fct>  <int>
 1 Bob   Green      3
 2 Drew  Blue       1
 3 Jim   Blue       2
 4 Jim   Red        2
```

If you want a function, then wrap this up in a function definition:

```
my_mode_func <- function(df){
df %>% 
   subset(complete.cases(df)) %>%
   group_by(Name) %>%
   count(Color) %>%
   mutate(max = max(n)) %>%
   subset(n == max) %>%
   mutate(Keep = case_when(
      n > 1 ~ TRUE,
      n == 1 & Color == head(Color,1) ~ TRUE,
      TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>%
   subset(Keep) %>%
   select(Name, Mode = Color, Count = n)
}
```